# D3 component does not re-draw after receiving new props

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am building an small app on React.js and I am using D3 to draw cubes corresponding to props it receives.

```
class Visual extends React.Component {

renderD3 = (records, selector) => {
    const data = records;
    console.log('inside renderD3', data);
    // It logs out most updated props every time it receives new props

    const visual = this.props.connectFauxDOM('div', selector);
    d3
        .select(visual)
        .attr('class', 'visual-wrapper')
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(data) // bind data
        .enter()
        .selectAll('div') 
        .data(d => d3.range(d.duration / 5).map(() => d)) 
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'block')
        .style('background-color', d => d.color);
}

componentDidMount() {
// it is just for generating gray grids for background setting, please ignore 
    this.renderD3([{duration: 300, color: '#e6e6e6'}], 'defaultBox')
}
render() {
    this.renderD3(this.props.records, 'box')
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="line-container">{this.props.defaultBox}</div>
            <div className="line-container">{this.props.box}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

What I want to achieve is that once `visual` component receives new props, D3 re-draws with new color(new props have different colors).

so far, inside `renderD3` function, it receives new props and on console, it does log new props correctly but cubes still have same color. The thing is that if I hash-refresh, then the color changes as in D3 draws cubes with new props.

I have imagined that D3 cubes will redraw (or update) cubes automatically once `Visual` component re-renders every time it receives new props. But thought inside `renderD3` function, it receives new props and logs new props on every re-render, D3 cubes do not change.

I am fairly comfortable with react but have little understanding of D3.
I am using react-faux-dom for integrating d3 with react by the way.

I'd appreciate any insight.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using the `connectFauxDOM` tool which is really reserved for animations when you don't need them, as far as I can tell? (I could be wrong here...)

There's a known issue with the documentation, it's not clear that you don't need to use this tool. You should just be able to use the normal stateless API:

```
const ReactFauxDOM = require('react-faux-dom');

class Visual extends React.Component {
  renderD3 = (data) => {
    console.log('inside renderD3', data);
    // It logs out most updated props every time it receives new props

    const el = ReactFauxDOM.createElement('div');

    d3.select(el)
      .attr('class', 'visual-wrapper')
      .selectAll('div')
      .data(data) // bind data
      .enter()
      .selectAll('div') 
      .data(d => d3.range(d.duration / 5).map(() => d)) 
      .enter()
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'block')
      .style('background-color', d => d.color);

    return el.toReact();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="line-container">{this.renderD3(this.props.records)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you're intending on using animations, you will need `connectFauxDOM`. If you don't need to do that sort of thing then the normal `createElement` and then `toReact` flow should be a lot easier to work with. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
let divs = d3
    .select(visual)
    .attr('class', 'visual-wrapper')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data) // bind data
    .enter()
    .selectAll('div') 
    .data(d => d3.range(d.duration / 5).map(() => d));

    divs.enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'block')

    //update
    divs.style('background-color', d => d.color);
```

For update you will need to break the code like this in your render method.

Reference: [here](https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was rather a problem of using a wrong method of module I am using. but thanks for kind reply.